# State check of custom type check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I have a state of this custom type:

```
  interface DataType { [key: string]: string;}

  const [data, setData] = React.useState<DataType>({});
```

and I then try

```
console.log(data === {})
```

Why does it return false?

And how can I check wether the state is still `{}`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare `data === {}` and equality check is performed based on type and reference.

An object is not equal to another object. You need to check if the data is an object and not null or array and has no keys to see if its empty object

```js
const isEmptyObject = (data) => {
    if(data !== null && typeof data === 'object' &&!Array.isArray(data)) {
       return Object.keys(data).length === 0;
    }
    return false;
}


console.log(isEmptyObject({}));
console.log(isEmptyObject({x: 1}));
```